# Copy row data into another column description from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with a complicated problem that I will try my best to describe.

I have a text file that has the following information

**Customer Name: Zack       Customer Number:12345**

10.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

10.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

**Customer Name: Larry    Customer Number:00099**

1.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

1.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

**Customer Name: James    Customer Number:99999**

5.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

5.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order

And So on..... in the same format.

What I want to do, is add the *Customer Name* value, "**Zack**" and *Customer Number* "**12345**" to the end of the line and get rid of the current format. 
Eventually ending up with this new format.

10.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order Zach 12345

10.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order Zack 12345

1.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order Larry 00099

1.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order Larry 00099

5.4  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order James 99999

5.5  2014556 - FSV Poly  -1.50 Feb 16 6 Each Unit Order James 99999

My thinking is something like... if line starts with a number then add the last customer Name value and customer Number value to the end of the line???

Is this even possible?

Thank you so much for your time!

Here is my code:

```
import re
file = open('Orders.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    if line.__contains__('Customer Name') or line[0].isdigit():
         print(line.lstrip())
```

And here is a better example of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be careful with opening a file, you have then to call to file.close() !

What you could do is iterate through the file and change the customer Name and number every time you find one

Here is my take:

```
customer_number = 0
customer_name = ''
with open('Orders.txt', 'r') as file: # Usually it's how files are opened
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if line == '': # We get out of the loop when we're finished
            break
        if 'Customer Name' in line:
            # Change customer number and name
            # Quite hacky way to do it
            listline = line.split('Customer')
            customer_name = listline[0]
            customer_number = listline[1]
        else :
            print('%s, %s, %s' % (line.strip(), customer_name, customer_number))
```

Note that at the end of the line will be written 'Name: yourcustomername', and 'Number: yourcustomernumber' with this method.
You can quite easily get only name and number of this but I'll let you find out yourself :)

I'd also recommend you to save your changes in a file rather than simply print them.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you explain the Change customer number and name, by parsing it? Also why cuatomer_name has no value?

Comment: Edited my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: You are amazing!! Thanks :)